# How to control transparency of faces in Opengl

Tags: python, pyopengl

I use `glColor4fv()` with input of a tuple i.e (1,0,0,0.5) to assign the color of a face before using `glBegin(GL_QUADS)` but for some reason with or without transparency the color of the last draw face is always visible irrespective of faces before it viewed by the camera. The colors with Opacities less than 1 doesn't seem to blend together when viewed. Am I missing something

```
l = facelist(a)
glBegin(GL_QUADS)
glColor4fv(Color[a])
for a in l:
    glVertex3fv(Vertex[l[a]])
glEnd()
```

Comment: Please add some of the data points you are using. You are assuming the error is with your use of glColor4fw but without seeing the actual data being passed to it that is hard to confirm.

Comment: You have to enable [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending) and to disable the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) (if it is enabled). `glEnable(GL_BLEND)` [`glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml) `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`